# I have to write a source code on software sales. I don't know what my mistake is.

Tags: java

I have to write a program that asks users to enter number of packages purchased. The program should then display the amount of discount and total amount of purchase after discount. I designed by program around this..

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class softwareSales
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      double Package = 99, discount, priceBfDiscount, discountPrice, totalPrice;
      int quantity;

      System.out.println("This is a software sales program");

      System.out.println("Enter number of packages");
      quantity = input.nextInt();

      System.out.println("Enter price of package");
      Package = input.nextDouble();

      System.out.println("Enter gross price");
      priceBfDiscount = input.nextDouble();

      priceBfDisc = Package * quantity;
      discountPrice = priceBfDisc * discount;
      totalPrice = priceBfDisc - discountPrice;

      System.out.println("The price before discount is $" + priceBfDisc);
      System.out.println("The discount price is $" + discountPrice);
      System.out.println("The total price is $" + totalPrice);



      if (quantity >= 10 && quantity <= 19)
      {
         System.out.println("The discount is .20");
      }
      else if (quantity >=20 && quantity <=49)
      {
         System.out.println("The discount is .30");
      }
      else if (quantity >=50 && quantity <=99)
      {
         System.out.println("The discount is .40");
      }
      else if (quantity >=100)
      {
         System.out.println("The discount is .50");
      }  







   }
```

I don't know what the mistake is. It keeps saying that there is no symbol for priceBfDisc. So if somebody could help  me identify my mistake, i would really appreciate it.

Comment: Use Java naming conventions (classes start with capitals, variables with lowercase) and an IDE (I like Eclipse). These will make writing and debugging your code much easier.

Comment: Also, learn to use Ctrl+F (or Cmd+F if you are on a Mac).

Comment: Declare your variables.

Comment: In java variables within method should be assigned to some values before use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
double Package = 99, discount, priceBfDiscount, discountPrice, totalPrice;
```

This is where your problem is, besides the error of `priceBfDics` not matching.

You need to declare all of these variables

```
//Either like this
double packageCost;
double discount;
double priceBfDiscount;
double discountPrice,
double total;

// Or like this
double packageCost,discount, priceBfDiscount, discountPrice, total;
```

Comment: It is telling me that "the variable discount might not have been initialized." what does that mean?

Comment: to initialize is to do something like this `discount = input.nextDouble()`, which you did.  You have to make sure all the variables have been initialized, meaning given a value, before you can do something with it, like print (which you are trying to do)

Comment: what is the 99 for? If you are getting the input for `package` from the keyboard, I don't understand what the 99 is for.  Also, I don't know if you left the code that I pointed out, in your program, but it should all be deleted except for `double package`

Comment: look at my edit. that's how you should have your variable declared

Comment: if i delete everything else, how can i find the price before discount and everything? Once the program is compiled, it needs to display price of discount and total price after discount

Comment: first of all, what is the 99 for?

Comment: I'm not sure if we're on the same page here, but I meant just replace `double Package = 99, discount, priceBfDiscount, discountPrice, totalPrice;` with this `double package, discount, priceBfDiscount, discountPrice, total;`

Comment: it is the value of the Package. Like it is the price of the package.

Comment: value meaning like dollar value or an id number?

Comment: and how is the package relevent to your code? You're not printing it out or using it anwhere beside getting it from the input

Comment: value meaning dollar value

Comment: if it's a dollar value then it should be declared and initialized at the same time. So change `double product;` to `double product = 99;` and leave the rest the same. But what I don't understand is if you have a price set at 99, why are you getting it again from the input?

Comment: its relevant b/c it is the price of the package.. and the number of packages (quantity) determines how much discount is given

Comment: yea i don't know why I did that.

Comment: ok, so now, why are you prompting the user for a price for the package again if you already have the value set to 99?

Comment: Oh sorry, and one more thing, You can't use `package` as a variable. It's a reserved Java keyword. LOL. So change it to `packageCost`.

Comment: ok thank you! and if i initialize the discount, which i did.. it asks me to enter the discount.. but then what is the point of my if else statements.. because when the user puts in the number of product, that should determine the discount based on my if and else if statements. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: oooooooooh! I think I see what you're trying to do now. You want the discount to be calculated based of the user input. Then you have to initialize `discount` in your `if` statements.  Instead of printing in your `if` statements, use `discount = (whatever the discount is)`

Comment: And finally, move all the `if` statements right below `priceBfDiscount = input.nextDouble();`.  The code is read in a linear manner, so the `discount` has to be declared before you can use it here `discountPrice = priceBfDisc * discount;`.

Comment: i did that but then it says discount has to initialized

Comment: If you did everything I said, It shouldn't say that. Your `if` statments should look like this `if (your conditions) { discount = whatever the discount is}`.  <-- This initializes your `discount`. Next, I said to move all the `if` statemnts to right below `priceBfDiscount = input.nextDouble();` and above `priceBfDiscount = input.nextDouble();`.  This MUST be done, or else you will get the message that discount is not initialized because you would be trying to use it here `discountPrice = priceBfDisc * discount;` before it's initialized. You get what I'm saying?

Comment: if (quantity >= 10 && quantity <= 19)
      {
         discount = .20;
         
      }
      else if (quantity >=20 && quantity <=49)
      {
         discount = .30;
         
      }
      else if (quantity >=50 && quantity <=99)
      {
         discount = .40;
         
      }
      else if (quantity >=100)
      {
         discount = .50;
         
      }

Comment: Yup. you got it. And did you place it where I told you? It should work just fine.

Comment: yea i put it below the priceBfDisc = input.nextDouble()

Comment: it does not.. it says "variable discount might not have been initialized"

Comment: In the `discount` declaration, put this `double discount = 0;` and try to compile and see what happens

Comment: just replace `double discount;` with `double discount = 0;`. This will declare and initialize at the same time

Comment: Also make sure all you calulations are correct when they print out

Comment: yea they were.. and you got it haha

Answer (score 8):

Read the error message. You didn't ever declare a `priceBfDisc`; you declared `priceBfDiscount`.

Comment: the OP really didn't declare anything if you look closely.

Comment: @peeskillet What are you talking about? The declaration is perfectly valid; try compiling it. Only one of the variables is *initialized*, but it's immediately overwritten anyway, and the fact that one's named with a capital letter means nothing to the compiler.